# Time for water levels to equalize

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Suppose that someone dumps some quantity of water into the ocean somewhere. Also, assume that no other water level changes are occurring. How long does it take for the change in water level to "propagate" to the other side of the world?

Comment: Are you asking about the physics behind the water flow? If we described the equations for two containers of water connected by a pipe of known radius would that be useful? The literal answer is probably not possible to calculate because there are too many variables involved e.g. topography of the sea floor.

Comment: Pouring in the quantity of water will start a surface wave, which travels at a speed depending on the wavelength (longer = faster), and as @John said, that depends on the depth. After a couple circumnavigations, the wave will dissipate, leaving the water deeper. Not a simple problem.

Comment: @JohnRennie Those equations would certainly be interesting to see, but I'm unsure of how exactly to apply it to this case, which as you say is much more complex. What if we assume ocean depth is constant and equal to its average? I'm mostly interested in a very rough approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can approximate this by assuming that information is passed only at the [speed of sound in the medium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound) and ignore all other affects (shape of the sea floor, depths, tides, weather, marine life, etc).

In this, case the speed of sound in water is about 1.5 km/s. For the Atlantic ocean, the distance from New York to England is about 2800 km, so it would take about 1900 seconds (30 minutes). For the Pacific ocean, it's about 8200 km from Japan to San Francisco; that journey would propagate in about 5500 seconds (90 minutes).

Comment: He's not asking how long the sound will take to travel, he's asking how long it will take for the water levels to equalise...

Comment: @JonStory: To a first order approximation, the rate it takes for the information that water is being added to pass from point A (where the water is being dumped) to point B (the other side of the ocean) *is* the speed of sound.

Comment: I agree that the information that water had been added to the system would propagate at the speed of sound, but actual changes in height would manifest as gravity waves, not acoustic waves.  These waves would probably travel at a speed more like $\sqrt{g \Delta H}$.  Think about what happens when somebody jumps into a pool. The entire thing doesn't instantly (speed of sound) rise, slow waves slosh across the surface.

Comment: @user3823992 When you say that information is propagated at the speed of sound, but not actual changes in height, what do you mean? How is the information represented besides in height change? Or do you mean that there is some height change at sound speed, just not the entire expected change?

Comment: In this case the 'information' would petty much amount to sound.  You would only see motion due that pressure to the degree that water is compressible (about  $0.005 \% Atm^{-1}$, really tiny).

Answer (score 0):

"An amount of time"

It completely depends how much water is dumped "dumped" into the ocean.

Other than that, we'd need to know how large the "connection" is between the two bodies of water. Eg water flowing into/out of the Mediterranean from/to the Atlantic has to travel through a fairly narrow passage. Between the Pacific and Indian oceans, however, the "gap" is huge.

Your question has far too many assumptions and not enough detail to even be able to approximate it, and any answer would only ever be an approximation without significant amounts of detail.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it is an extended comment.

Comment: Depends on your outlook, I suppose. The "answer" is that we don't know, and can't without more detail, which I think warrants an answer, as the Original Poster can't provide us with enough detail to even estimate a "real" answer.

Comment: A comment is meant to ask for clarification of a problem (what you are doing here). An answer resolves the issue the OP has (which you are not doing here).

Comment: Normally I'd agree, but I don't believe this question can be clarified enough to have an answer, therefore 'there is no answer' is, in fact, the answer.